# How to get HTML text from Adobe Flex Builder RichTextEditor?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml, rich-text-editor

How to get HTML text from inputed and edited text into [Adobe Flex Builder RichTextEditor control](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_10.html)? I mean **with valid HTML** coming from the Flex RichTextEditor component

Not Badly formated HTML, with no spaces, with tags not closed!

So we have some text edited with RTE a-la 
[alt text http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/images/RTE1.png](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/images/RTE1.png)

We want to get its content as HTML. how to do such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a really nice class called *RteHtmlParser* which can translate RTE generated "html" to html and back. I've been using it on a project and it works nice. You can see a live example and get source code here: http://blog.flashweb.org/archives/7

Answer (score 1):

What version of the framework are you using?  When I try to create a duplicate of your linked example using 3.2, I get well-formed HTML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:RichTextEditor id="rte" />
    <mx:TextArea height="{rte.height}" width="{rte.width}" text="{rte.htmlText}" />
</mx:HBox>  
</mx:Application>
```

My Flex 3.2 output looks like this, ugly but well-formed:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="12" COLOR="#009900" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="1"><B>This is the way the world ends</B></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

The same text in your example site gives the badly formed:

```
<P text-align:CENTER;><span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px; color:#009900;  "><strong>This is the way the world ends</strong></span>
```

(You might post the source for your example; you have "View source" enabled but it's not actually available.)

EDIT:

The external code you're using does the following, among other modifications:

```
pattern = /<\/P>/g;
str = str.replace(pattern, “”);
```

So that explains the missing `</p>` tags.

I'm not sure what their use case was, but it appears different from what you want.  If you want to clean up the default `htmlText` returned by the RichTextEditor, you might consider revamping the blog code to suit your needs.